# Return dissimilarly sized matrices?

Tags: r

Each time my code is called it returns a couple of matrices but the size changes from call to call, like it does in this example code below. I do not know ahead of time what the array sizes will be. How do I determine from what's returned what the dimensions were on the two arrays? Do I have to pass those back explicitly in the return or is there a better way to do this?

Thanks

```
ReturnTwoArrays = function(){
  x1=sample(1:4)[1]
  x2=sample(2:4)[1]
  A1 = matrix(data=1,nrow=x1,ncol=x2)
  x3=sample(1:5)[1]
  x4=sample(2:4)[1]
  A2 = matrix(data=2,nrow=x3,ncol=x4)

  return(c(A1,A2))
}

C1 = ReturnTwoArrays()
C2 = ReturnTwoArrays()

C1
C2
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem here is that you cannot use `c` on two dissimilar matrices. You should return a list:

```
  ....
  return(list(A1, A2)) 
   }
```

Then you access the elements of that list:

```
 C1 = ReturnTwoArrays()
 C1[[1]]
 c2[[2]]
```